# Processing - SVG unable to load after Illustrator

Tags: processing

I'm trying to load an SVG in Hype-Processing. You can do this through stating:

```
HShape d = new HShape("ruby.svg");
```

Initially it works on an SVG I obtained from online. However when I group the objects in Illustrator and group some paths, and try to load the svg again, it then fails. The error is in the gist below.

```
Could not parse -1 for --display
Ignoring <style> tag.
parsed: M,161.1,29.8,c,0,-.1,...,0
unparsed: .1.4,11.53,11.53,0,0,0,1.9,4.2,8.8,8.8,0,0,1,.6,1,15.61,15.61,0,0,0,2.6,3.9,1,...,29.8,Z
HYPE.pde:1:0:1:0: RuntimeException: shape command not handled: .1.4
Finished.
Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).
```

I'm assuming the cause of the error, is the Creative Cloud version of illustrator that I'm using. Either that or maybe an issue with grouping paths.

Has anyone else had this error, if so how would you resolve it? I was thinking of trying to alter the SVG code itself.
If not is there anyway to ensure illustrator saves in a backwards compatible state?

note: I mainly wanted to group paths, so that some of the objects are the same colour based on symmetry. Colour is determined randomly.

Answer (score 5):

When you save an SVG with Illustrator it adds a `<style>` tag so it can reuse classes. However, Processing doesn't support this tag, spitting out the warning: `"ignoring style tag"`. This effectively removes all color from the sketch, resulting in shapes being displayed as black. The easiest fix is to use "in-line" styling when you save the SVG from Illustrator so Processing can access the information. To do this 1) choose "More Options" in the SVG Options dialog, and then 2) choose "Style Attributes" in the drop CSS Properties drop down.

You can open the SVG in a text editor to confirm the shapes look something like this (where `style` is an attribute of the shape):

```
<polygon style="fill:#87CFC8;" points="18.3,15.2 37.4,4.1 56.6,15.2 37.4,26.2 "/>
```

And here is the setting in Illustrator:

[image: illustrator screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

Seems illustrator when exporting saves an SVG slightly differently than when simply using SAVE. Using export creates the issue above, so the SVG can't be loaded into Hype. But saving it, seems there is no issue!

Answer (score 0):

i ran into this issue myself just now. I changed three things, now it works again:

1. Saved as SVG-Version 1.1
2. unchecked "use slicing"
3. Selected "style properties (entities)" for CSS-Style

Hope this helps!